# Mix procedural displacement with a texture-based displacement for Cycles?

Tags: shader-nodes, displacement

I want to mix procedural displacement with a texture-based displacement.

While I can combine two BSDF nodes using the Mix Shader node, the Displacement input of the Material Output node does not accept input from the Mix Shader. Is there a way to mix two displacement outputs? Thanks! Blender 3.6.2, Windows 11

Comment: Mix the 2 images into a Color Mix that you plug into the Displacement node?

Comment: That works! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mix the 2 textures in a *Color > Mix Color* node (in *Multiply* mode or whatever other mode), it should give something like that:

[image]